# I now get "sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments" but I've made no page change. What could cause this?

Tags: kohana

I have a page on an inherited site that has locations. User enters their address and it searches based off an existing db of locations and shows 10 nearest. It links to google maps. Up until 2 weeks ago it worked fine. Now I get sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments on the locations.php page.

What causes this to happen? I'm utterly lost in this framework.

error given: An error was detected which prevented the loading of this page. If this problem persists, please contact the website administrator.
application/controllers/locations.php [87]:
sprintf() [function.sprintf]: Too few arguments

That line on that page has this:

```
//Count reaulta
$query = sprintf("SELECT *, ( 3958 * acos( cos( radians('{$geocode[2]}') )      * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('{$geocode[3]}') ) +     sin( radians('{$geocode[2]}') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS 'distance' FROM     'locations' HAVING 'distance' < '50'");
$db=new Database;

$query = $db->query($query);

$total = $query->count();
```

Again, as I haven't made any changes to this page I don't understand what could have suddenly caused this issue.

Comment: Do you think including the relevant code might be required in order to get a relevant answer?

Comment: Well I just added the particular line mentioned in the first part of the error. It also has a lengthy stacktrace bit. not sure if that is helpful or not.

Comment: Based on the line you edited in, the problem you describe is not found directly within the code (but another is and is related) -- but rather in the input; one of the variables you're passing in contains a percent sign indicating an argument that should be present but isn't. The real problem though is that you're using sprintf() like this to build a SQL query -- if this is on a web site, you're a hacked site waiting to happen. Do _not_ run this on a site others have access to.

Comment: Again, I inherited this and have pushed to move off this framework. And the 'input' is an address. That has been the set up since the site was built so why would it now decide that a variable contains something new?

Comment: I can't answer the _why did things change_ question. I can tell you that sprintf() takes one or more arguments, and the first one has hints of the required additional arguments -- those hints are a % followed by a code to indicate the type. As to inheriting it -- I'm not criticizing _you_, just the code you're working with... it's a quintessential example of how to not handle database queries in web code. Instead of building the query like this, you want to have that code rewritten to use the `->prepare()` and `->execute()` statements -- these will avoid a serious security flaw.

Comment: So if I'm gonna track down this required additional argument where should I be looking? I see the code for creating pagination, and code for getting geocodes. I don't see the page requiring anything other than // Include Markdown
   require Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'Markdown');  I will be notifying my bosses how unsecure this is. Maybe they'll FINALLY move off this framework.

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help further, but I'll reinforce -- I don't think the error is truly that you're missing an argument, but rather that the $geocode variable has text that contains a % causing a false requirement for that argument... you need to track the source of this data. (First though, log the data to verify its content.)

Comment: Since there are no arguments to `sprintf` (you are using variable interpolation instead), just remove the `sprintf` - since it's not needed - or switch to use the `sprintf` properly instead of the variable interpolation.  Either way should fix this issue.